# Workmanager not working with delay in android 12 Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-workmanager

Hey I am working WorkManager in kotlin. I didn't understand some code and getting me this error. Could you someone explain me in more details.

```
2022-01-06 16:48:33.501 14483-14483/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.app, PID: 14483
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expedited jobs cannot be delayed
            at androidx.work.WorkRequest$Builder.build(WorkRequest.java:326)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerHelper.setupNotificationWorkerForNextLaunch(TrackerHelper.kt:124)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerHelper.setReminderOff(TrackerHelper.kt:36)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerHelper.switchReminder(TrackerHelper.kt:70)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerSettingsViewModel.switchReminder(TrackerSettingsViewModel.kt:34)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerSettingsViewModel.enableReminder(TrackerSettingsViewModel.kt:100)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerSettingsViewModel.setupReminderRow$lambda-1(TrackerSettingsViewModel.kt:85)
            at com.example.app.tracker.TrackerSettingsViewModel.lambda$5Q3PVjBphM6lb1pU0jZdN9GXKaE(Unknown Source:0)
            at com.example.app.tracker.-$$Lambda$TrackerSettingsViewModel$5Q3PVjBphM6lb1pU0jZdN9GXKaE.onCheckedChanged(Unknown Source:2)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:222)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.setChecked(SwitchCompat.java:1095)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.toggle(SwitchCompat.java:1090)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:144)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
            at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70564373) it working in android 11 or below. After that I tried this [medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-workmanager-on-android-12-f7d483ca0ecb) post to run android 12 but I am getting above error.

I tried code is

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider"
        tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
    </provider>
```

**1.** Can someone explain what is doing above code in details please.

**WorkerClass.kt**

```
class WorkerClass(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, workerParams){

    override fun doWork(): Result {
         // calling function
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**HelperClass.kt**

```
fun setupNotificationWorkerForNextLaunch() {
        val delayDuration = currentDate.timeInMillis
        val dailyWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WorkerClass>()
            .setInitialDelay(delayDuration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
            .addTag(REMINDER_WORK_TAG)
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(Application.appContext).enqueue(dailyWorkRequest)
}
```

I added this code from medium post

```
.setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
```

**2.** Can someone explain how to work this in android 12 as well. I want to create a notification at particular time every day. How can I achieved this through WorkManager. Thanks

Comment: The XML addition to AndroidManifest.xml removes WorkManager's default initialization and allows you to have a custom initialization: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration

You should use it only if you have your own custom initialization.

Comment: @pfmaggi do you know how to use setExpedited with delay in workmanager ?

Answer (score 3):

WorkManager doesn't guarantee that your work runs at an exact time. And most apps don't need that in the first place, unless your app is an alarm or a calendar app.

If you want to run something regularly on a roughly 24 hourly basis, [`PeriodicWorkRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) is the API to use.

Using the `setExpedited` API lets WorkManager know that the request is potentially important to the user and should run ASAP. Hence the restriction on delays on that API.

Comment: I want to use work manager like a alarm clock. So it could be possible with `PeriodicWorkRequest`?

Comment: It won't. WorkManager executes work when the device allows it to, rather than waking it up unnecessarily.

Comment: So which api need to use to work like alarm manager?

Comment: I want user to choose time according to his convenience to trigger work manager.

Comment: May I know, in Android 12, how does `setExpedited` work under the hood? Pre-12, to mark a job as important and not killed by OS, it is using Foreground service + notification under the hood. In Android 12, background app can no longer launch foreground service. So, what mechanism `setExpedited` is using, to tell OS this is an important job and shouldn't be killed? Thanks.